# Convert date from JSON to Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, json, sql-server

`"tgl_dok":{"date":"2018-07-02 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"`}

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#table').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": false,
    "responsive": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "../adapter/ArReport/rptPenerimaanHarian/data.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: ({kd_entitas: kd_entitas,
        tglAwal: tglAwal,
        tglAkhir: tglAkhir})
    },
    "columns": [
    {
      title: 'Date',
      data: "tgl_dok",
      "type": "date", 
    },
    {
      title: 'Receipt. No',
      data: "no_dok"
    },
    ]
  })
});
```

How can I show date format like `DD/MM/YY` in `datatables`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyDate = CONVERT(datetime, '2018-07-02 00:00:00.000000', 121)
```

about convert rules look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)